# Python dictionaries adding different values to a key?

Tags: python, dictionary

I want to make a function that goes through a list and makes a dictionary with keys for each thing in the list and values of the one thing in the list following the key.

```
def function(s : str) -> {str:{str}}:
    listt=list(s)
    dictt= {}
    for i in listt[:-1]:
        if i not in dictt:
            dictt[i] = set()
        dictt[i].update(listt[listt.index(i)+1])
    return dictt



print(function('bookeeper'))
```

should return:

```
{'b': {'o'}, 'k': {'e'}, 'p': {'e'}, 'o': {'o', 'k'}, 'e': {'e', 'p', 'r'}}
```

but actually returns:

```
{'b': {'o'}, 'k': {'e'}, 'p': {'e'}, 'o': {'o'}, 'e': {'e'}}
```

Comment: I remember seeing this question a few minutes ago: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22956714/python-dictionaries-adding-values-to-a-key

Comment: grate :) can u please help me ...

Comment: which python version you use?

Comment: @user1153551: Python 3, obviously. The function annotation gives it away.

Comment: in my terminal show me perfect result that you want

Comment: 3.3.3 I hate how the versions are so different... wow

Comment: I have been trying for like an hour i keep getting: {'k': {'e'}, 'b': {'o'}, 'p': {'e'}, 'o': {'o'}, 'e': {'e'}}

Comment: @user1153551: I very much doubt that.

Comment: what you say i m understand say me clearly..? - @MartijnPieters

Comment: @sshashank124: I am really surprised at the hostile response this post got the first time around. Loads of people having no clue about function annotations, I see.

Comment: @user1153551: I very much doubt you got the OPs code to output the desired output. The code, as posted by the OP, produces the wrong output, not the desired output, and never could produce the right output. I'm saying that I don't think you could have made it work on your machine without changing the code.

Comment: @MartijnPieters, Me too. I don't know about this new notation so I kept my distance from the question. I didn't downvote since I couldn't verify the correctness.

Comment: @sshashank124: see the [Python 3 function definition reference](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/compound_stmts.html#function-definitions), as well as [PEP 3107](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3107/)

Comment: sorry @MartijnPieters i m not focusing last dictonary word but my output is `{'p': {'e'}, 'k': {'e'}, 'b': {'o'}, 'e': {'e'}, 'o': {'o'}}` is my mistake sorry for alert me.

Comment: @MartijnPieters, Interesting. Thank you. I will look at it.

Answer (score 3):

Don't use `list.index()`; that'll only match the **first** occurrence of a letter; for `'o'` it'll never find the second `'o'`; you'll only repeatedly add the same characters to the sets.

Use [`enumerate()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#enumerate) to add an index to your loop, instead:

```
def function(s : str) -> {str:{str}}:
    listt=list(s)
    dictt= {}
    for next_index, char in enumerate(listt[:-1], 1):
        if char not in dictt:
            dictt[char] = set()
        dictt[char].update(listt[next_index])
    return dictt
```

I started `enumerate()` at 1 instead of the default 0 so it always represents the *next* position.

Demo:

```
>>> def function(s : str) -> {str:{str}}:
...     listt=list(s)
...     dictt= {}
...     for next_index, char in enumerate(listt[:-1], 1):
...         if char not in dictt:
...             dictt[char] = set()
...         dictt[char].update(listt[next_index])
...     return dictt
... 
>>> print(function('bookeeper'))
{'p': {'e'}, 'o': {'o', 'k'}, 'e': {'p', 'r', 'e'}, 'b': {'o'}, 'k': {'e'}}
```

Now that it is working, lets simplify this a little; use [`dict.setdefault()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict.setdefault) to add the set to the dictionary when the key is missing, for example. Strings are already sequences, no need to cast them to a list either:

```
def function(s : str) -> {str:{str}}:
    dictt = {}
    for next_index, char in enumerate(s[:-1], 1):
        dictt.setdefault(char, set()).update(s[next_index])
    return dictt
```

Instead of `enumerate()`, we could also use `zip()` to pair up the letters of the word:

```
def function(s : str) -> {str:{str}}:
    dictt = {}
    for char, next_char in zip(s, s[1:]):
        dictt.setdefault(char, set()).update(next_char)
    return dictt
```

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is that `index()` always returns the first index in the string, so you'll be adding the same character to the set over and over.

Try something like

```
def function(s : str) -> {str:{str}}:
    dictt = {}
    for pos, char in enumerate(s[:-1]):
        if char not in dictt:
            dictt[char] = set()
        dictt[char].update(s[pos+1])
    return dictt
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is the another answer:

```
def func(string):
    arr = set(string)
    res = {}
    for char in arr:
        index = [i for i in range(len(string)) if string[i] == char]
        temp = []
        for i in index:
            if i == len(string) - 1:
                continue

            temp.append(string[i + 1])

        if temp:
            res[char] = temp

    return res

func('bookeeper')

>>> {'b': ['o'], 'e': ['e', 'p', 'r'], 'k': ['e'], 'o': ['o', 'k'], 'p': ['e']}
```

Comment: This produces lists, not sets. It'll produce the wrong result for `toppop` for example (two times `p` after `o`).

Comment: It is also extremely inefficient; your algorithm uses O(N^2) time; for each additional character in the word you double the time taken.